# What is Dell OpenManage Ubuntu Repository?

Tags: dell, repository

What is [Dell OpenManage Ubuntu & Debian Repositories](http://linux.dell.com/repo/community/ubuntu/)?
Do we need to install for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a repository to install [Dell OpenManage](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/1757.dell-openmanage-systems-management-tools.aspx), a software designed to manage deployments of dell servers. It's usually only used on big IT shops.

You shouldn't install it unless you have a rack with some hundreds of dell servers in the backyard ;).

Comment: I'm going to remove it now!

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use this if you are running a DELL PowerEdge Server, and need to monitor it over a network. You wouldn't need this unless you were using a server more then likely, but you could install this via CLI to work on a DELL Desktop with RAID [Haven't tested the second scenario].

The installation procedure for Ubuntu is not for the novice since it requires some tweaking and is used for monitoring production servers used in business settings [e.g. rack servers in Data Centers].